# Passing Arguments on-the-fly in the Body of a Post API Call

Tags: javascript, json, rest, angular, post

I have been using API call functions in my Angular app where certain arguments can be passed in the component where and when they're being used. That's easy enough to handle. What I'm not sure how to do is let a user pass a parameter within the body of a post call to the API. How does one do that? In this instance below, I want the user to be able to pass a query parameter, and a value. This is what my service function API call looks like:

```
getByQuery(page, pagesize) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    const body = { "addresses.postalCode" : "10009" };
    return this.http.post
      (`https://api.someurl.com/${this.ver}/clients/search?apikey=${this.key}&page=${page}&pagesize=${pagesize}`,
      body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

How would I handle setting this up so the items in the body of the call here can be passed on-the-fly?

Would I simply pass in an empty object, like so?

```
getByQuery(page, pagesize, {}) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add a new argument to your `getByQuery` function and build up your body objects whenever you invoke the function:

```
getByQuery(page, pagesize, body) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    return this.http.post
    (`https://api.someurl.com/${this.ver}/clients/search?apikey=${this.key}&page=${page}&pagesize=${pagesize}`,
    body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

And when invoking your function:

```
getByQuery(1, 20, { "addresses.postalCode" : "10009" });
```